# autoencode in notepad ++

Tags: integration-testing, notepad++

Very often i need to encode text file from UCS-2 Little Endian to ANSI and save it with the same name. Is it possible to automate this process ? For example to run Notepade ++ with the parameters , or use special script ?

Comment: Have you tried the Notepad++ macro function?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this on 5000+ files. I used AutoHotKey to send keystrokes

1. in file list window, press enter on filename so it gets open in Notepad++
2. after Notepad++ gets activated and ready, trigger the conversion
3. close document in Notepad++
4. switch back to file list window
5. send down arrow to proceed to next line

I have temporarily disabled syntax coloring (I had Visual Basic files) to get files open faster.

My macro (<kbd>WinKey+F5</kbd>) using file list in Total Commander (instead of Windows Explorer) was:

```
SendMode Input
DetectHiddenWindows, On
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

#F5::
    KeyWait,AppsKey

    Loop, 10 {
        MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
        If (xpos == 0)
            Break
        Send {F4}
WaitNPP:
        Sleep, 20
        IfWinNotActive, .*Notepad
            ;MsgBox nax
            Goto, WaitNPP

        Send !c
WaitDialog:
        Sleep, 50
        IfWinNotActive, .*Column
            Goto, WaitDialog

        Send {Esc}
        Sleep, 50
        Send ^+{F8}^s^w
        ;!+F8 was created as custom shortcut in N++
        Sleep, 100
        Send #1
WaitTC:
        Sleep, 20
        IfWinNotActive, .*Commander
            Goto, WaitTC

        Send {Down}
        ;Run C:\Tools\notifu.exe /p "Conversion to UTF-8" /m "1 of 10" /d 500
        ;Sleep, 500
    }
Return
```

The loop is set to process 10 files.

Inside Notepad++ I triggered conversion by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F8</kbd> which I defined inside the Notepad++ in settings.